# JS thats clicks link with specific name between <a>...<a/> tags. Should i use window.find(string).click(), Xpath or object.innertext?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I'm trying to write a javascript that clicks a link on a page with a specific name only described between the link tags

```
<a>"Name of product"</a>
```

This is the code on the webpage.

```
<a href="/shop/category/k3xmhac9o/lvt89rd5q" class="name-link">"Name of product"</a>
```

The link is scrambled and generated randomly but the name of the products is available. 
I Have tried

```
window.find("Name of product").click()
```

but it does not work

I read that this might work

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title = 'Name of product']")).click();
```

but i am running the javascripts through an applescript and i am not sure if i can use Webdriver through applescript.

Is there any other way to click the link?

I also read that "object.innerText" might be an option

Comment: Do you have standard DOM access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a nice concise way to achieve what you're looking for

```
var tags = document.querySelectorAll('a.name-link')
for(var i = 0; i < tags.length ; i++) {
    if(/Name of product/.test(tags[i].innerHTML)) {
        tags[i].click()
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i was looking for. I am also using the loop since there are many products with the same name, but in different colors. 
I have to run through each afterwards to check for colorways so i changed the "tags[i].click()" to "window.open(tags[i])"
Do you have any idea if there is a way to have it run faster? It takes a full 6 seconds to click open 6 tabs. It seems like a lot compared to how fast 6 tabs load if i cmd+click 6 times

Answer (score 0):

If you have standard DOM access, you can do it like this:

```
var link = Array.prototype.find.call(
    document.querySelectorAll("a.name-link"),
    function(a) {
        if (a.innerHTML.trim() == '"Name of product"') { // Is it really in "?
            return true;
        }
    }
);
if (link) {
    link.click();
}
```

Note: You may need to shim `Array#find` on older browsers.

Or without needing to shim `Array#find`, actually:

```
Array.prototype.some.call(
    document.querySelectorAll("a.name-link"),
    function(link) {
        if (link.innerHTML.trim() == '"Name of product"') { // Is it really in "?
            link.click();
            return true;
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is "name-link" the actual class name (indicating that there would be many on a page with that exact name) or will it reflect the unique 'name' of the product?  If it is unique you could use `document.querySelector('.name-link').click()`.  If it isn't unique, is there more context you could give, like a more reliably selected element and then find this element: `parentElement.getElementsByClassName[0].click()` 
or 
`parentElement.querySelector('.name-link').click()`