# Run applescript application on ANY left click. Mouse listener or third party extension?

Tags: macos, applescript, listener, mouselistener

I want a simple script/app to run on any left click with my mouse.
It is for an applescript that enters data on a site as soon as i click a link.

I have looked at different shortcut extensions and i cant find any that works.
I simply want to tie an action to the left click.

I have also searched for applescript mouse listeners that would be able to detect any left click and then run the rest of the script, but i cant find any.

It is important that the script runs the instant the mouse is clicked.

Comment: You could easily create something that opens up the page (and changes it). You could just click on the AppleScript to run it then.

Comment: It's actually kind of hard. I have to click a product whose link is randomized so the only identifier is the picure itself. There is also a product description between the link tags but they do not contain the color of the product so i still have to open like 6 of each product and then run a script on each that checks for color. All in all this takes 6 seconds using querySelectorAll() and innerHtml. What i want is a script that runs the instant i click on it after it becomes available

Comment: You're trying to solve this in a very ineffective way. You might be able to accomplish what you want if you use a combination of scraping and applescript. I could probably write a regex to find the link of the picture if I had a link to the page source.

Comment: Cool. Here's the source http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/tops_sweaters That page is the best to start from since the items have a link with the name of the product between the links tags. 
Here's a thread i started about creating a Javascript that could find the specific product from the description between the tags. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36791883/js-thats-clicks-link-with-specific-name-between-a-a-tags-should-i-use-wi
That solution however is too slow. It takes 5-6 sec. for it to find and open the correct products. And then i have to scrape.

Comment: I have also tried opening all products and then scraping, but that takes to long aswell

Comment: It seems to show all the colors, styles and if they are in stock on the one page... What exactly is wrong with using the information from that page?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, the problem is when a create a loop that runs through each link tag it ends up taking 5-6 seconds. Im not sure why. Furthermore the color description and product name are two seperate links, so i have no way of checking whether the current link for a product i am looking at is red or white and when i am looking at a color link i dont know which product it refers to. At least i cant see a way to combine the information from the two links into one link or object

Comment: I'm scraping the data and I seem to be able to get both the style and color.

Comment: Okay. I'm not exactly sure how you do it. I mean i want to click into one product with one specific color and then proceed from there. I am only able to do that by getting all the link tags with the class "name-link" using querySelctorAll(a.name-link). I then run through the loop checking for the the product name using .innerHtml. I then open all those products in new tabs and the run window.find on each to check for the color. I heard there used to be a way to load html from a link using JS without actually opening the page but that it was removed due to security problems.

Comment: I have it printing something like this: `http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/tops_sweaters/shop/tops-sweaters/rv0ajtm2u/t1ihf4b6w    Leopard Vest    Leopard
http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/tops_sweaters/shop/tops-sweaters/jwz6rko81/zebuxhq2o    Tinsel Sweater    Black. `It's possible to use applescript to open up the link in a new window. But this is really the answer to a different question...

Comment: How do you do that? And does those links work? When i put them in they just redirect to the main page. Those two products have different urls when i inspect the elements or just visit the page. I wasn't asking whether it was possible to open the link in a new window? All i am saying is right now i have to open them all and check for color. 
This loop is the one that runs and basically opens all products of a kind

"var tags = document.querySelectorAll('a.name-link')
for(var i = 0; i < tags.length ; i++) {
    if(/Tinsel/.test(tags[i].innerHTML)) {
        window.open(tags[i])
    }
}"

Comment: I forgot to remove a few chars. I am getting output like this: `http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/tops-sweaters/rv0ajtm2u/t1ihf4b6w    Leopard Vest    Leopard` The link should be able to be put into the browser (by some means) the middle word is the name of the item and the last thing is the "color". I have all three of those pieces separately in the code. You really need to ask another q if you want me to answer this any further...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a mouse listeners that you can run in an **AppleScript** script.

```
set myAppleScriptPath to quoted form of "/Users/myUserName/Desktop/someScript.scpt" -- change it to the path of your appleScript

set pyScript to quoted form of ("import os
from AppKit import NSObject, NSApplication, NSEvent, NSLeftMouseUpMask
from PyObjCTools import AppHelper
class AppDelegate(NSObject):
    def applicationDidFinishLaunching_(self, aNotification):
        AppDelegate.myMonitor=NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask_handler_(NSLeftMouseUpMask, self.leftMouseClick)

    def applicationWillTerminate_(self, notification):
            NSEvent.removeMonitor_(AppDelegate.myMonitor)
            AppHelper.stopEventLoop()

    def leftMouseClick(event):
        os.system(\"osascript  " & myAppleScriptPath & "\")

tDeleg=AppDelegate.new()
NSApplication.sharedApplication().setDelegate_(tDeleg)
AppHelper.runEventLoop()")

-- this run the NSLeftMouseUp listener, and this listener launch an Applescript
do shell script "/usr/bin/python -c " & pyScript & "> /dev/null 2>&1 &" -- this launch the "Python" application , and quit this script
-- to stop the listener, quit the "Python" application from the Dock
```

This script launch the listener. For each left click (on mouse up), the listener launch an **AppleScript** specified in the first line.

To stop the listener, just quit the "**Python**" application from the **Dock**

If you want a listener on the mouse down, change `NSLeftMouseUpMask` in the script to `NSLeftMouseDownMask`

Comment: Thanks! This completely works. I have to start the script a bit before starting "clicking" because the python script has to start up i guess. Besides that it works great. Thanks a lot!